# Mapeate values from a row that poins out several FK to the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1

```
ID EXTERNALCODE Brand_T Brand_E Brand_C

1    569859       1        2    3
2    545479       4        2    5
```

Brands have the same Foreign Key to table 2, they are IDs of table 2.

Table 2

```
ID Brand_Code

 1   eee

 2   465656
    
 3   456U99
     
 4   4OREFUOREFJ9

 5   r56
```

FINAL RESULT SHOULD BE:

```
ID EXTERNALCODE  Brand_Code

1   569859       eee

1   569859       465656

1   569859       456U99

2   545479       4OREFUOREFJ9

2   545479       465656

2   545479       r56
```

What I have tried:

```
Select   
      Table1.Id
     ,Table1.EXTERNALCODE
     ,Table2.Brand_Code as Brand_Code
     ,T2_E.Brand_Code  as Brand_Code
     ,T2_C.Brand_Code as Brand_Code
 
 FROM 
     Table2      Left join Table1 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Brand_T
     Table2      Left join Table1 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Brand_E
     Table2      Left join Table1 ON Table2.Id = TabLe1.Brand_C
```

But this query is giving many duplicates.

Comment: You are struggling here because your design is not well normalized. You should have two tables instead of one for "Table 1". You have violated 1NF with repeating groups. Also, your sample query is confusing because the syntax is invalid.

Comment: Where is the syntax wrong? 
Care you explain the former part : "(...) have two tables instead of one for "Table 1"? Thanks.

Comment: In your query you have "Table2 T2_E" and "Table2 T2_C" in front of the last two lines. That is just random extra characters in your query which are invalid.

Comment: As for the normalization part, you have a ExternalCode that can have some brands associated with it. Instead of a column for each brand you should have a table for this. Most likely the relationship between your main table and brand would be a many to many which would mean you also need a bridging table.

Comment: I cannot alter the tables, so how can I solve this without changing the tables?

Comment: In the title of your question the first word is "Mapeate". What does that mean?

Comment: It only means: take the ID of the BRAND and mapeate it to its name /brand code. Example: the id brand C for the EXTERNAL CODE 569859  is 1 which mapeates it to eee in table 2.

Comment: Repeating the unknown word "mapeate" is not making it clear. There is no word like that in English and I can't find one in any language.

Comment: To map. In this case, it would be assigning  the id  brand C for the EXTERNAL CODE 569859 the name code as eee.

Comment: I will use the union. It will work this way. :)

Comment: The union? Did you see the answer I posted?

Comment: yes I have read and it worked with union all. :) Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't fix the normalization issue you could query against your existing structures something like this.

```
declare @Table1 table
(
    ID int
    , EXTERNALCODE int
    , Brand_T int
    , Brand_E int
    , Brand_C int
)
insert @Table1 values
(1, 569859, 1, 2, 3)
, (2, 545479, 4, 2, 5)

declare @Table2 table
(
    ID int
    , Brand_Code varchar(50)
)
insert @Table2 values
(1, 'eee')
, (2, '465656')
, (3, '456U99')
, (4, '4OREFUOREFJ9')
, (5, 'r56')

select t1.Id
    , t1.EXTERNALCODE
    , t2.Brand_Code
from @Table1 t1
join @Table2 t2 ON t2.ID in (t1.Brand_T, t1.Brand_E, t1.Brand_C)
```